# Difference between OpenSSL TLS/SSL versions

Tags: security, ssl, smtp

I am currently implementing OpenSSL's TLS/SSL standards into my mail service, allowing my users to select the TLS/SSL version they want. Here is the list of versions:

```
["TLSv1","TLSv1_server","TLSv1_client","SSLv3","SSLv3_server","SSLv3_client","SSLv23","SSLv23_server","SSLv23_client","TLS","TLSv1_1_server","TLSv1_1_client","TLSv1_1","TLSv1_2","TLSv1_2_server","TLSv1_2_client"]
```

I did some Googling on what the difference of the options are, and I understand that some versions are deprecated, or shouldn't be used because of security issues, such as `TLSv1`. I don't understand the difference between the `client` vs `server` ones, but from my own testing, the `server` options return errors when trying to send a mail with it.

So my question is - of that list, what should I remove?

Comment: Where are you seeing this list of versions? Also: Why would you let users choose a TLS version? You should always use the highest version available.

Comment: There's nothing special about the TLS versions provided by OpenSSL. They are the same as called out by the RFCs.

Answer (score 1):

What you show are not SSL/TLS versions but various types of SSL contexts which also include the usable SSL/TLS versions. This means the `*_server` "versions" are all SSL contexts which should be used on the server side where you usually also need a certificate. The `*_client` variants are for the client side of the TLS handshake, i.e. the one which initiates the TLS handshake.

Within a mail client you don't want to use any server specific SSL contexts because with these the  mail client would expect the peer to start with the TLS handshake which it does not.

For more details see the man page of [SSL_CTX_new](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html) which has a detailed description of what all these different contexts mean.

> ... allowing my users to select the TLS/SSL version they want.

While your specific implementation is wrong the idea of letting users chose the protocol version is wrong too. Instead you should just use a generic context without limitations (apart from disabling insecure versions) so that it automatically picks the best protocol version during the TLS exchange. Selecting specific protocol versions should only be done in case the peers TLS stack is broken, like for stacks which simply refuse a TLS 1.2 handshake instead of replying with TLS 1.0 in case they don't support TLS 1.2.

Comment: Note through 1.0.2 'for hysterical raisins' the generic methods retain the old and now misleading names `SSLv23_{client_,server_}method` In 1.1.0, released last year but not yet adopted everywhere, they are renamed to `TLS_*method`.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for - thank you. I do intend to have a default version (TLSv1_2_client is what I had in mind), but there was a case where some versions were causing issues for the customer, so we decided the best fix was to have some other versions for them to choose from.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: `TLSv1_2_client_method` supports *only* TLS 1.2, i.e. can not connect to servers supporting only TLS 1.0. It is better to use `SSLv23_client_method` but disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 using `SSL_CTX_set_options` as described in the documentation. This way it will support TLS 1.0 ... TLS 1.2 and pick the best one.

Comment: Hey @SteffenUllrich, are you saying you can use `SSL_CTX_set_options` on `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS`? I checked the docs, and it wasn't immediately clear..

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: I'm not sure what is not immediately clear. To cite from the docs: *The list of protocols available can be further limited using the SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 and SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2 options of the SSL_CTX_set_options or SSL_set_options functions.*

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I guess to me it also isn't immediately clear what `SSL_CTX_set_options` is relevant to me wanting to remove some options from `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS`.. Are you saying to use https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html rather than `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS`? Are we even talking about the same programming language? The above examples look like C to me..

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: my recommendation was to use a specific method and adapt it. To cite myself: *It is better to use SSLv23_client_method but disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 using SSL_CTX_set_options as described in the documentation.*.